# Windows phone sdk installation in 8.1 32-bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone

I have Windows Operating System 8.1  - 32 -bit and I installed Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

I want to start work on Windows phone Apps, so please assist me which Sdk is need to be
install and all the process up to creating First Application.

Answer (score 0):

You need windows 8.1 x64 pro to install the windows phone 8.1 sdk and use the emulators.  I believe that you can still install the sdk on the 32 bit version of the os but you need to debug on an actual windows phone.

Comment: Thanks Ken,

Can it possible on 32 bit OS ?

If it possible, please provide me proper steps for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry you will the windows phone 7 sdk to develop for windows phone on a 32 bit os

Comment: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/03/26/wpsdk-711-now-available.aspx